# TypeError: $ (…).typeahead is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, typeahead.js, searchkick

I have been breaking my head for 2 days on how to resolve this. I am using searchkick + typeahead in my rails 5.1.2 app. Tried all combos of placing the //=require typeahead.bundle.js (above/below jquery) but the error never goes away. Below is my application.js file

```
//= require wNumb.js
//= require twitter/typeahead
//= require typeahead.bundle.min
//= require typeahead.bundle
//= require typeahead
//= require nouislider
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.particleground.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require thesaas.min.js
//= require core.min.js
//= require noty.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require layout.js
//= require bootstrap-checkbox.min.js
//= require switch.min.js
//= require switchery.min.js
//= require jquery.sparkline.min.js
//= require tether.min.js
//= require moment-with-locales.min.js
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
//= require legacy.js
//= require daterangepicker.js
//= require app-menu.min
//= require vendors.min
//= require app.min
//= require morris.min.js
//= require echarts.js
//= require unslider-min.js
//= require raphael.min.js
//= require icheck.min
//= require utils.min.js
//= require checkbox-radio.min.js
//= require jquery.steps.min.js
//= require jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.js
//= require turbolinks
//= require cocoon
//= require dropzone
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require jquery.validate.min.js
//= require gauge.min.js
//= require odometer.js
//= require chat-application.js
//= require wow.js
//= require social-share-button
//= require_self
```

Now the script is being called from application.js (tried it from articles.js as well, but not working),

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var articles = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/articles/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });
    $('#articles_search').typeahead(null, {
        source: articles
    });
});
```

But I am still getting 'TypeError: $ (…).typeahead is not a function'. Is this a jquery issue?

Comment: are the twitter/typeahead and  typeahead not conflicting?

Comment: they could be, I have tried using each of them separately, but still the same error.

Comment: I'm not much help but I can confirm that we use typeahead and we have `require jquery` then `require typeahead` (just typeahead, not the other variants)

Comment: so did a tiral and erro by placing the //= require typeahead below, found vendors.min was conflicting so moved it up. thanks :)